# gulp uglify with explicit js file names vs. wildcard ones

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

I am a gulp newbie. I am using VS 2015 Update 3 to do my project. For that project, I have several service and controller classes that are written using TypeScript. I use gulp to sort, concat, uglify those angular js files that are transpiled by .ts files. Here the orders of service and controller files are important so I use "gulp-angular-filesort" recipe before concatenating those files. I try 2 versions.

For version 1 (see codes below. The task is named as **"min:appcompExp"**), I list js files in order explicitly in the gulpfile.js file, and the resulted minified (min) file is working and there is no problem when I run my project.

For version 2 (see codes below. The task is named as **"min:appcompExp2"**), I use wild cards for listing SOURCE js file names for shorting codes in the gulpfile.js. However, the resulted minified (min) file is created but it it not working when I run my project.  The error looks like dependency injection issue:  controllers  cannot find their corresponding service DI although I see the resulted min file for this version contains all service and controller classes in it.  I use ngularFilesort = require("gulp-angular-filesort"), but it does not help for Version 2.

One specific DI error with Version 2 using gulp:

```
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: ContactSrvcProvider <- ContactSrvc <- ContactCtrl
```

Can somebody please explain why using wild cards for SOURCE js file names is not working with gulp?

The following is my gulpfile.js that lists 2 versions of concat and uglify service and controller classes:

```
/*
This file in the main entry point for defining Gulp tasks and using Gulp plugins.
Click here to learn more. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518007
*/

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    inject = require("gulp-inject"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    print = require("gulp-print"),
    angularFilesort = require("gulp-angular-filesort"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"); 


// concatenated/bundled files 

// vendor js scripts
var pathsCssSrc = "./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/*.min.css";
var pathsNglibSrc = [
    "./bower_components/angular/angular.min.js",
    "./bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js",
    "./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", // must before "bootstrap.min.js"
    "./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
];

var pathsAppmoduleSrc = [
    "./app/app.js",
    "./app/Constants/Constants.js",
    "./app/routes.js",
    "./app/models/*.js"
];


// destinations
var pathsDest = { build: ".build/", subspa : "spa/", indexfile : "./index.html" };

pathsDest.cssDest = pathsDest.build + "css/appStyles.min.css";
pathsDest.nglibDest = pathsDest.build + "nglib/nglib.min.js";
pathsDest.appModuleDest = pathsDest.build + pathsDest.subspa + "app.min.js";


// tasks
....



////// services, controllers

gulp.task("min:appcompExp", function () {

// I explictly list ALL of js file names and their orders of js file names are important.
// The resulted min js file working when I run my project.

    var target = gulp.src(pathsDest.indexfile); // important: root folder must be specified before file name "index.html"

    var comp = gulp.src([ "app/services/SessionSrvc.js",
                        "app/services/UtilSrvc.js",
                        "app/services/BaseSrvc.js",
                        "app/services/ContactSrvc.js",
                        "app/services/AvatarSrvc.js",
                        "app/services/LoginSrvc.js",
                        "app/services/RegisterSrvc.js",
                        "app/services/presidentsSrvc.js",

                        "app/controllers/BaseCtrl.js",

                        "app/controllers/LoginCtrl.js",
                        "app/controllers/LogoutCtrl.js",
                        "app/controllers/RegisterCtrl.js",
                        "app/controllers/PresidentCtrl.js",
                        "app/controllers/PresidentDetailCtrl.js",
                        "app/controllers/ContactCtrl.js",
                        "app/controllers/AvatarCtrl.js"]);

    var dest = ".build/spa/appcomp.min.js";


    return target
    .pipe(inject(comp
        .pipe(print())
        .pipe(concat(dest))
        .pipe(angularFilesort())
        .pipe(uglify()) // Minifies the concatenated js file.
        .pipe(gulp.dest(".")) // important: otherwise there is no files stored
        , { name: "appcomp" }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./")); // important: root folder must be specified like so


});


//////////////////////////// 

gulp.task("min:appcompExp2", function () {
// using wild cards for SOURCE js codes for shorting codes
// I got runtime error when running my project: DI problem - controllers cannot find their service classes.

    var target = gulp.src(pathsDest.indexfile); // important: root folder must be specified before file name "index.html"

    var comp = gulp.src(["app/services/*.js",
                        "app/controllers/*.js"]);

    var dest = ".build/spa/appcomp.min.js";


    return target
        .pipe(inject(comp
            .pipe(print())
            .pipe(concat(dest))
            .pipe(angularFilesort()) // this does not help though
            .pipe(uglify()) // Minifies the concatenated js file.
            .pipe(gulp.dest(".")) // important: otherwise there is no files stored
            , { name: "appcomp" }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./")); // important: root folder must be specified like so


});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use wildcards in your `gulp.src()` i.e. `["app/services/*.js", "app/controllers/*.js]`, gulp is reading all js files inside `app/services/` and `app/controllers/` directory in sorted order.

When you explicitly list the source files in `gulp.src()` i.e. `["app/services/SessionSrvc.js", "app/services/UtilSrvc.js", app/services/BaseSrvc.js", etc.]`, gulp reads those js files in that particular order.

The reason why your `"min:appcompExp2"` gulp task is not working is because the use of wildcards in `gulp.src()` is messing the order of js files being processed by gulp. Whereas your `"min:appcompExp"` gulp task is working because you are explicitly listing the js files in the order it should be processed.

I bet if you modified the parameter for `gulp.src()` in your `"min:appcompExp"` gulp task so that the js files are in sorted order, it would fail the same way that your `"min:appcompExp2"` gulp task did:

```
[
"app/services/AvatarSrvc.js",
"app/services/BaseSrvc.js",
"app/services/ContactSrvc.js",
"app/services/LoginSrvc.js",
"app/services/SessionSrvc.js",
"app/services/UtilSrvc.js",
"app/services/presidentsSrvc.js",
"app/services/RegisterSrvc.js",

"app/controllers/AvatarCtrl.js"
"app/controllers/BaseCtrl.js",
"app/controllers/ContactCtrl.js",
"app/controllers/LoginCtrl.js",
"app/controllers/LogoutCtrl.js",
"app/controllers/PresidentCtrl.js",
"app/controllers/PresidentDetailCtrl.js",
"app/controllers/RegisterCtrl.js",
]
```

I am assuming that it is a case-insensitive sorted order for `presidentsSrvc.js`.

Comment: so, to maintain the orders of Angular dependency injections (services always go before controllers), I have used gulp-angular-filesort recipe, but it does not help. To make gulpfile.js simple and maintainable , wild cards are used but the resulted min js file failed. Controllers get undefined services.  So, how can I solve the problem for Version 2?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but I believe `var comp = gulp.src(["app/services/*.js", "app/controllers/*.js"]);` is reading all services before controllers. I think the problem lies in the ordering of js files in `services` directory and/or the ordering of js files in `controllers` directory. I noticed there is `BaseSrvc.js` and `BaseCtrl.js`. Do other services inherit BaseSrvc.js? And do other controllers inherit BaseCtrl.js? If so, I believe gulp needs to read those .js files before other inherited services and controllers. If that's the case, I don't think you can simply use wildcards.

Comment: BaseSrvc is extended by other other services.  UtilSrvc is injected by other  services.  BaseCtrl is used only by the shell page view aka index.html.

Comment: I might be wrong, but `"min:appcompExp"` gulp task works because you put `UtilSrvc.js` and `BaseSrvc.js` services before other services and because you put `BaseCtrl.js` controller before other controllers.

Comment: Thank you.  Version 1 I explicitly list js files as they were in index.html file using src of script tags before I move them to the gulpfile.js.  I prefer using wild cards for shorter and matainable codes of SRC files for the gulp task. So in future if  I have new service or controller I do not need to update the gulpfile.js. It is easy to make a mistake if I use Version 1 to forget to list a new service or controller file in the SRC part of the task.  And the big problem is it is hard for me or other people who work on the project to remember which file depends on which in 2 or 3 months.

Comment: Yeah, you have to explicitly list js files. Your 2nd gulp task using gulp-angular-filesort won't help you concat your angular js application files in correct order. It will only help inject those files in correct order when your modules are spread across multiple files.